# Convert a list of list of objects to string

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists

I've a list of list of objects like `List<List<Event>>`.

How can I override `ToString()` such that each internal list will be shown in a single line of command prompt?

```
public override string ToString(List<List<Event>>)
{
     return ?
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're using this for, but might be worth serializing it in to json or yaml?

Comment: @KevinSmith: I don't think so. These events are just some strings corresponding to a finite state machine. All I need is a method to print them. Serialization sounds to be much complicated for this task.

Answer (score 2):

```
public override string ToString(List<List<Event>> events)
{
     return string.Join(", ", 
         events.SelectMany((list) => list)
             .Select((ev) => ev.ToString()));
}
```

1. Take the list of lists and flatten it with `.SelectMany()`
2. Convert each `Event` to a string re-using `.ToString()`
3. Join the array of strings into one string with comma separated (can be changed).

**Edit 1**
Given that the base method signature is `string ToString()` without any parameters you probably need to reference a field or property in your class and not define a separate `string ToString(List<List<Event>> events)`.

```
public class SO 
{

    List<List<Event>> events;

    public override string ToString()
    {
         return string.Join(", ", 
             events.SelectMany((list) => list)
                 .Select((ev) => ev.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a brief explanation of the steps.

Comment: The `.ToArray()` seems unnecessary.

Comment: The compiler throws the error for this method: `BacktrackingPathFinder.PathFinder.ToString(System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<BacktrackingPathFinder.Event>>)': no suitable method found to override`

Comment: Remove the `override` keyword if you are not overriding a method from a base class. You didn't post any details of `Event` or where this method is declared in so I just used your method signature.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override string ToString(List<List<Event>> lle)
{
    StringBuilder res=new Stringbuilder(your_guess_of_lenght_here);
    foreach(List<Event> le in lle){
        foreach(Event e in le){
            res.Append(e+"any_separator_of_elements");
        }
        res.Append("\n");
    }
    return res.ToString();
}
```

Something like this? I don't know your event string representation, you may want to change that.

Comment: Might as well replace `res.Append("\n");` with `res.AppendLine();`

Comment: or `Environment.NewLine` (that is actually pasted by `AppendLine()`)

Comment: What if I have no guess about the value of `res` variable?

Comment: StringBuilder isn't static in its length. It's just that it has to expand constantly when you preset its length to 5 for example. So a bit more cpu work, but nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public override string ToString(List<List<Event>> listOflistOfEvents)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        listOflistOfEvents.ForEach(delegate(List<Event> listOfEvents)
        {
            result.AppendLine();
            listOfEvents.ForEach(events => result.Append(events + ","));
        });
        return result.ToString();
    }
```